# Best way to convert array of objects into Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert the array of objects into object. I've done with the below logic. Is there is a best way to handle this?

[Fiddler Version](http://jsfiddle.net/wLg8qdqy/1/)

```js
var before = [{
  "x": ["2015-10-14T01:59:59.999+05:30", "2015-10-14T03:59:59.998+05:30", "2015-10-14T05:59:59.997+05:30", "2015-10-14T07:59:59.996+05:30", "2015-10-14T09:59:59.995+05:30", "2015-10-14T11:59:59.994+05:30", "2015-10-14T13:59:59.993+05:30", "2015-10-14T15:59:59.992+05:30", "2015-10-14T17:59:59.991+05:30", "2015-10-14T19:59:59.990+05:30", "2015-10-14T21:59:59.989+05:30", "2015-10-14T23:59:59.988+05:30"]
}, {
  "CleanCoal": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Middelings": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Prime": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "SpiralProd": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}];

var after = {};

for (var i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
  var keys = Object.keys(before[i]);

  after[keys] = before[i][keys];
}

console.log(after)
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(after))
```

Comment: your version is not true, if `{a:1, b:4, ....}` object's key will be more than one.

Comment: Your approach only works because the inner arrays each have only one key. With more than one it would fail. You need a second loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over an array, and you forgot to iterate over the nested array if there are multiple elements inside of an object.

So, the code in question will not work for

```
var arr = [{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}];
```

**Demo**

```js
var before = [{
  "x": ["2015-10-14T01:59:59.999+05:30", "2015-10-14T03:59:59.998+05:30", "2015-10-14T05:59:59.997+05:30", "2015-10-14T07:59:59.996+05:30", "2015-10-14T09:59:59.995+05:30", "2015-10-14T11:59:59.994+05:30", "2015-10-14T13:59:59.993+05:30", "2015-10-14T15:59:59.992+05:30", "2015-10-14T17:59:59.991+05:30", "2015-10-14T19:59:59.990+05:30", "2015-10-14T21:59:59.989+05:30", "2015-10-14T23:59:59.988+05:30"]
}, {
  "CleanCoal": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Middelings": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Prime": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "SpiralProd": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}];

var after = {};

before.forEach(function(obj) {
  // obj here is the element of the array, i.e. object

  // Looping over all the keys of the object
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    // key here is the key of the object
    after[key] = obj[key];
  });
});

console.log(after);
document.writeln('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(after, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I also need to change the date format from string to date type. I've updated the code snippet. How efficiently I can convert?

Comment: @PremkumarJayaseelan Please ask a different question for date format change

Comment: Hi, brother, Thanks for `JSON.stringify(after, 0, 2)`. I didn't know. What do you think about my answer. Can you advise me(is it good way or not)?

Answer (score 3):

We use the best of functional programming in JavaScript:

Using `reduce` we don't need to add temporary variables to the outer scope.

`for (var i in obj)` is generally faster than `Obj.keys(obj).forEach`: https://jsperf.com/for-in-versus-object-keys-foreach

```js
var before = [{
  "x": ["2015-10-14T01:59:59.999+05:30", "2015-10-14T03:59:59.998+05:30", "2015-10-14T05:59:59.997+05:30", "2015-10-14T07:59:59.996+05:30", "2015-10-14T09:59:59.995+05:30", "2015-10-14T11:59:59.994+05:30", "2015-10-14T13:59:59.993+05:30", "2015-10-14T15:59:59.992+05:30", "2015-10-14T17:59:59.991+05:30", "2015-10-14T19:59:59.990+05:30", "2015-10-14T21:59:59.989+05:30", "2015-10-14T23:59:59.988+05:30"]
}, {
  "CleanCoal": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Middelings": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Prime": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "SpiralProd": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}];
var after = before.reduce(function(dst, src){
  // import every key: val in src into dst
  // and keep doing it for every element in the array.
  for (var key in src) 
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(src, key)) 
      dst[key] = src[key];
  return dst;
}, {}); // start with an empty object to avoid modifying items in before array.

document.writeln("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(after, null, 4) + "</pre>")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not optimal. You should explain why your code meets the OPs requirements.

Answer (score 3):

In latest browsers [ecmascript 5], we have `reduce` which returns an object

try below

```js
var before = [{"x":["2015-10-14T01:59:59.999+05:30","2015-10-14T03:59:59.998+05:30","2015-10-14T05:59:59.997+05:30","2015-10-14T07:59:59.996+05:30","2015-10-14T09:59:59.995+05:30","2015-10-14T11:59:59.994+05:30","2015-10-14T13:59:59.993+05:30","2015-10-14T15:59:59.992+05:30","2015-10-14T17:59:59.991+05:30","2015-10-14T19:59:59.990+05:30","2015-10-14T21:59:59.989+05:30","2015-10-14T23:59:59.988+05:30"]},{"CleanCoal":["0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"]},{"Middelings":["0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"]},{"Prime":["0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"]},{"SpiralProd":["0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"]}];


var object = before.reduce(function(o, v, i) {
  o[i] = v;
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(object);
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pscytrgj/

Comment: *reduce* doesn't necessarily return an object, it returns whatever the callback returns as an accumulator (which can be any value). MDN provides a [polyfill for *reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) so older browsers are accommodated too.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, that's true! kinda learning for me as well :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through `JSON.stringify()`

```js
var before = [{
  "x": ["1", "2"],
  y: {
    a: 3
  }
}, {
  "CleanCoal": ["0.00", "0.00"],
  b: 4
}, {
  "Middelings": ["0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Prime": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "SpiralProd": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}];

var after = {};
var b = "",
  i = -1;
while (before[++i]) {
  var str = JSON.stringify(before[i]);
  b += str.slice(1, str.length - 1);
  if (before[i + 1]) b += ",";
}
after = JSON.parse("{" + b + "}");
console.log(after);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(after, 0, 3) + "</pre>")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about Object.assign?

```js
var before = [{
  "x": ["2015-10-14T01:59:59.999+05:30", "2015-10-14T03:59:59.998+05:30", "2015-10-14T05:59:59.997+05:30", "2015-10-14T07:59:59.996+05:30", "2015-10-14T09:59:59.995+05:30", "2015-10-14T11:59:59.994+05:30", "2015-10-14T13:59:59.993+05:30", "2015-10-14T15:59:59.992+05:30", "2015-10-14T17:59:59.991+05:30", "2015-10-14T19:59:59.990+05:30", "2015-10-14T21:59:59.989+05:30", "2015-10-14T23:59:59.988+05:30"]
}, {
  "CleanCoal": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Middelings": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "Prime": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}, {
  "SpiralProd": ["0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
}];

var after = {};

before.map(function(i){
  return  Object.assign(after,i);
})


console.log(after)
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(after))
```